# Is there any disadvantage to store today date as static value in asp.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, static

In an asp.net application, I use this code:

```
public static DateTime DEFAULT_TODAY = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
```

Then I use this code to set calendar default day as today. Is there any problem with this?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me. Just use `DateTime.Now` if you want the `DateTime` of today...

Comment: What if the date changes? How are you going to update it tomorrow?

Comment: FerhatSayan and Alireza thanks for reply. You are right.

Comment: This still leaves me wondering, wat on earth were you thinking ?!?

Comment: Just for easy access. my class name GlobalVars. And I use every where in application as GlobalVars.DEFAULT_TODAY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This assumes the date does not change after program start. 46 years of living on this planet have teached me - time does move forward.

Just use in the code DateTime.Now.Date and finished.

Comment: Yes you are right. I realize my mistake. Thank you.

Comment: or could use DateTime.Today in place of DateTime.Now.Date.

Answer (score 3):

`DEFAULT_TODAY` will hold the same date until your application has not restarted. In ASP.net application it will not automatically update.

Example: 
FOR TODAY (2016-03-01): `public static DateTime DEFAULT_TODAY = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day); // It will return DEFAULT_TODAY =2016-03-01`

FOR TOMORROW (2016-03-02): `public static DateTime DEFAULT_TODAY = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day); // It will return same value DEFAULT_TODAY =2016-03-01`

You will not get updated datetime whenever date changes.